# Copyright on a research photography

Tags: research-process, advisor, authorship, research-undergraduate, copyright

I was part of a research group in a research institute I called 'X'. In this research we used a very interesting, colorful technique so I take some pictures for myself that are very artistic. Now I want to present them in a Scientific Photography contest organized by the same institute 'X'. I signed a confidentiality agreement with the institution and my research advisor. The thing is I need an author's written authorization for reproduction of the images in order to participate in this contest. At first I thought I was the author since I was the one who took the photo, but seems that in the agreement I signed says that all products of this investigation are property of the institute 'X' and I don't know if this has something to do but the camera was also property of the lab. So, who should I ask for the authors written authorization? Or I don't have to ask for it at all?

Comment: There is no "author" for a photograph. There is only a photographer/creator and copyright holder. Depending on your contract, your institute might hold the exclusive rights for use and distribution. If that is the case or if the confidentiality agreement covers the photograph you can't publish it without the institute's permission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask the head of the research group that you were part of.